# Google App Engine remote_api script not found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm setting up remote_api locally and this time around it's not working. I'm just following the instructions on the remote_api doc page for python here: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html

Which basically means I'm running the following command from the project app root (that contains app.yaml)

```
>> python $GAE_SDK_ROOT/remote_api_shell.py -s your_app_id.appspot.com
>> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/remote_api_shell.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The your_app_id  param is being changed to the actual app id on google's.

It's probably a simple thing, but not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `$GAE_SDK_ROOT` with the actual root directory of your GAE SDK. So, probably:

```
python ~/google_appengine/remote_api_shell.py -s ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not the path you specified. What would the path be for a mac? the app engine launcher app is located here: /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app but not sure where within the package contents the sdk is present

Comment: Here it is: /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/